# What is a word or phrase which means constantly changing?

Tags: word-request

I am writing an essay and I am writing a sentence which has to do with the ever changing world of computers with constant innovation.

This is what I have currently written "is insufficient to cope with the **ever evolving world** of the computing "

I need a better word for this

Comment: What do you mean by "better" — that is, what in particular is wrong with what you wrote, in your opinion? What criteria should a substitute satisfy?

Comment: @NathanTuggy The word evolving meant gradual and slow change which i thought didnt fit for a description of the IT industry i decided to use the word advancing instead of evolving which i feel is a better fit

Comment: I think _ever evolving_ is a good choice of word esp. if you want to imply _improvement_. Other words can be _dynamic_ or _ever changing_.

Comment: What is wrong with **rapidly changing**?

Comment: Just my opinion, but I think _evolving_ is a better word than _dynamic_ here...